# Code Migration Wizard in VB 2008

Tags: vb.net

I have come to know that there is a code migration wizard, that heps migrate from vb6 to vb.net.
How I can access that in vb2008?

Thanks
Furqan

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be [some tool support available](http://tinyurl.com/4yrqzrr).

Still, I would be skeptical to the use of the word *migrate* if you are making the technology monster-leap from VB 6 to .NET 4.0.

If your VB 6 application is really well designed with core business logic nicely isolated in separate classes, then those parts could perhaps be suited for migration.

But, if someone intends to support and maintain this app for another 10 years, you should consider whether a rewrite is a better option. That way it will be easier to start taking advantage of the efficiency gains provided by the new technology. I don't think there is any migration tool that will convert VB 6 code into e.g. anonymous methods, lambda expressions, linq, reflection and generics.

The need to consider a rewrite is particularly important if your long-lived application has suffered increases in code entropy and complexity over the years causing it to be hard to understand and difficult to maintain.

Comment: Don't bother with the Migration wizard unless your project is so trivial, that, well, there wouldn't be much of a point anyway. If you really WANT to migrate in an automated way, you might look into Francesco Balena's VBMigration Partner. http://www.vbmigration.com/ But it's not cheap and even then, there's work to do.